# Ocultar <td> vacios de tabla

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables

tengo una duda de algo que no tengo claro como hacer. Quiero crear una visual de una agenda de citas, en la que sale una tabla que salen los trabajadores y debajo las citas que tiene ese trabajador. Para ello, tengo una tabla en la que listo las citas que tengo en un calendario. En la tabla, creo un ciclo para montar los trabajadores y debajo el mismo ciclo para que se vea la cita de cada uno.

Funciona correctamente (Se muestran todas las citas debajo de cada trabajador) pero quiero que no se queden huecos libres. Ahora se muestra así:

```html
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>Trabajador1</td>
       <td>Trabajador2</td>
       <td>Trabajador3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>03/01/2023 </td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td>01/01/2023</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>03/01/2023</td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>04/01/2023</td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Y yo quiero que se muestre así, sin huecos libres:

```html
<table>
   <tr>
       <td>Trabajador1</td>
       <td>Trabajador2</td>
       <td>Trabajador3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>03/01/2023 </td>
       <td>03/01/2023</td>
       <td>01/01/2023</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td>04/01/2023</td>
       <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

¿Como puedo hacerlo? Os adjunto el código que tengo, gracias.

```
            $data = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM calendario_trabajadores WHERE inicio >= '$fecha'");
             if($lisc = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
                 echo '<div class="card-body"><table id="html5-extension22" class="table table-hover table-striped " style="width:100%">';
                 echo '<thead >';
                 //Ahora hacemos un ciclo de los trabajadores 
                 $consulta_trabajadores = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM usuarios order by nombre ASC");
                 if($cota = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_trabajadores)){
                    do{
                            echo' <th >'.$cota['nombre'].'</th>';
                    }while($cota = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_trabajadores));
                 }
                 echo '</thead>';
                  echo '<tbody>';
                 do{
                    echo'<tr>';
                    $id = $lisc['codigo'];
                    $id_user_asignado = $lisc['id_usuario'];
                      //En cada vuelta hay un evento. Hacemos el ciclo de trabajadores y si el id del usuario es igual al del trabajador lo mostramos 
                     $consulta_trabajadores = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM usuarios order by nombre ASC");
                     if($cota = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_trabajadores)){
                        do{

                            $iduserbucle = $cota['id'];
                            $fecha_inicio = $lisc['inicio'];
                            $iniciocita = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha_inicio));
                            $horainiciocita = date("H:i", strtotime($fecha_inicio));
                            //Si no tiene trabajador asignado no mostramos nada 
                            if($iduserbucle != 0){
                                //Aqui tenemos un trabajador en cada vuelta. Comprobamos y si es de este mostramos datos, si no vacio 
                                if($id_user_asignado == $iduserbucle){
                                    echo '<td> <strong>'.$iniciocita.' a las '.$horainiciocita.'</strong> <br> '.$lisc['titulo'].'</td>';
                                }else{
                                    echo '<td></td>';
                                }
                            }       
                        }while($cota = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_trabajadores));
                     }
                      echo'</tr>';
                 }while($lisc = mysqli_fetch_array($data));
                 echo '</tbody></table></div></a>';
             }
```

y aqui tengo el javascript del datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
     $('#html5-extension22 thead tr')
         .clone(true)
         .addClass('filters')
         .appendTo('#html5-extension22 thead');

     var table = $('#html5-extension22').DataTable({
         orderCellsTop: true,
         fixedHeader: true,
         responsive: true,
     "dom": 'B<"float-left"i><"float-right"f>t<"float-left"l><"float-right"p><"clearfix">',
     //"dom": 'Bfrtip<"lrtip"l>',
     "language": {
         "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Spanish.json"
     },
         initComplete: function () {
             var api = this.api();

             // For each column
             api
                 .columns()
                 .eq(0)
                 .each(function (colIdx) {
                     // Set the header cell to contain the input element
                     var cell = $('.filters th').eq(
                         $(api.column(colIdx).header()).index()
                     );
                     var title = $(cell).text();
                     $(cell).html('<input type="text" placeholder="' + title + '" size="10"/>');

                     // On every keypress in this input
                     $(
                         'input',
                         $('.filters th').eq($(api.column(colIdx).header()).index())
                     )
                         .off('keyup change')
                         .on('change', function (e) {
                             // Get the search value
                             $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
                             var regexr = '({search})'; //$(this).parents('th').find('select').val();

                             var cursorPosition = this.selectionStart;
                             // Search the column for that value
                             api
                                 .column(colIdx)
                                 .search(
                                     this.value != ''
                                         ? regexr.replace('{search}', '(((' + this.value + ')))')
                                         : '',
                                     this.value != '',
                                     this.value == ''
                                 )
                                 .draw();
                         })
                         .on('keyup', function (e) {
                             e.stopPropagation();

                             $(this).trigger('change');
                             $(this)
                                 .focus()[0]
                                 .setSelectionRange(cursorPosition, cursorPosition);
                         });
                 });
         },
         "ordering": false,
         "responsive": true,
        "order": [[ 0, "asc" ]],
        buttons: [
           
           {
             extend: 'pdfHtml5',
             footer: true,
             exportOptions: {
                columns: [ <?php             
                    $data = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM usuarios ");
             if($lisc = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) { 
                   $numerador = 0;
                    do{
                        echo $numerador.", ";
                        $numerador = ($numerador + 1);
                    }while($lisc = mysqli_fetch_array($data));
             }
                ?> ]
              },
             text: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save-file"></i><span> Generar PDF</span>',
             filename: 'Listado de Trabajos asignados',
           },
             text: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i><span> Imprimir</span>',
           }
       ],
       "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "Todos"]]
     });

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basándome en lo que quieres lograr, me puse a pensar en una forma de hacerlo empleando dos arreglos: uno para los nombres de las personas y otro para las citas de cada una. Esto es a lo que llegué:

```
<?php
$nombres = ['Juan', 'Javier', 'Jimena'];
$citas = [
    ['12/04/2023'], //Juan
    ['25/01/2023', '30/05/2023', '31/12/2023', '05/09/2023'], //Javier
    ['13/02/2023', '01/01/2023'] //Jimena
];

$table = '<table>';
$table .= '<thead>';
$table .= '<tr>';
foreach ($nombres as $nombre) $table .= "<th>$nombre</th>";
$table .= '</tr>';
$table .= '</thead>';
$table .= '<tbody>';

for ($i = 0, $rowsLength = count(max($citas)); $i < $rowsLength; $i++){
    $tr = '<tr>';
    for ($j = 0, $colsLength = count($nombres); $j < $colsLength; $j++){
        if (isset($citas[$j][$i])){
            $tr .= "<td>{$citas[$j][$i]}</td>";
        }
        else{
            $tr .= '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
        }
    }
    $tr .= '</tr>';
    $table .= $tr;
}

$table .= '</tbody>';
$table .= '</table>';
echo $table;
?>
```

Siendo el resultado exactamente lo que buscas:

[image: Tabla de resultados]

A partir de la lógica de lo que quieres obtener, las filas de la tabla las define el número de citas, mientras que las columnas se supeditan al número de nombres. Como deseas que las fechas de las citas de cada persona se listen todas debajo del nombre de la misma, el número de filas de la tabla tiene que corresponder al arreglo de citas con más fechas, para lo cual me apoyé de las funciones [max()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.max.php) y [count()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.count.php).

Ahora bien. Trasladando esa lógica a lo que tienes hecho, y con la finalidad de que generes un código más legible, te sugiero que primero guardes los datos correspondientes a los nombres y a las citas de una manera similar a la del ejemplo, de tal forma que solo te quedaría aplicar dicho código, previamente adaptado a las características que requieres.

Esto sería más o menos así:

```
<?php
$queryNombres = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'CONSULTA SQL PARA OBTENER LOS NOMBRES');
$nombres = [];
if (mysqli_num_rows($queryNombres)){
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryNombres)){
        $nombres[] = $rows['COLUMNA DEL NOMBRE EN LA TABLA'];
    }
}

$queryCitas = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'CONSULTA SQL PARA OBTENER LAS CITAS');
$citas = [];
if (mysqli_num_rows($queryCitas)){
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryCitas)){
        $citas[] = $rows['COLUMNA DE LA CITA EN LA TABLA'];
    }
}
?>
```

En la consulta de las citas, puedes apoyarte de la función [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php), de tal forma que puedas agrupar todas las citas de cada persona en un solo bloque y, al momento de asignar esos valores al arreglo de las citas, puedes generar el arreglo con cada una de las citas utilizando la función [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php).

Sería algo así:

```
<?php
$queryCitas = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(col_cita SEPARATOR '|') AS citas FROM tbl_citas GROUP BY fk_idPersona");
$citas = [];
if (mysqli_num_rows($queryCitas)){
    while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($queryCitas)){
        $citas[] = explode('|', $rows['citas']);
    }
}
?>
```

En donde *fk_idPersona* es la llave foránea dentro de la tabla de las citas que se relaciona con el ID de la tabla de los nombres, mientras que *col_cita* es el nombre de la columna en la tabla de las citas que alberga a las fechas de las citas y *tbl_citas* es la tabla de las citas.

Si se abstrae la funcionalidad del algoritmo que crea la tabla y la colocas dentro de una función, solo bastaría que la invoques en una línea:

```
function tablaHTML($cols = [], $rows = []){
    $table = '<table>';
    $table .= '<thead>';
    $table .= '<tr>';
    foreach ($cols as $field) $table .= "<th>$field</th>";
    $table .= '</tr>';
    $table .= '</thead>';
    $table .= '<tbody>';

    for ($i = 0, $rowsLength = count(max($rows)); $i < $rowsLength; $i++){
        $tr = '<tr>';
        for ($j = 0, $colsLength = count($cols); $j < $colsLength; $j++){
            if (isset($rows[$j][$i])){
                $tr .= "<td>{$rows[$j][$i]}</td>";
            }
            else{
                $tr .= '<td>&nbsp;</td>';
            }
        }
        $tr .= '</tr>';
        $table .= $tr;
    }

    $table .= '</tbody>';
    $table .= '</table>';
    echo $table;
}

tablaHTML($nombres, $citas);
```

De esta manera, tendrás un código más legible y, en consecuencia, más fácil de mantener, además de poder reutilizar el bloque generador de tablas cuantas veces lo requieras.

Puedes hacerlo de la manera explicada o bien adaptar lo descrito a la forma en la que trabajas, solo trata de no limitarte al copiar/pegar porque es muy probable que no vaya a funcionar; no olvides que este es solo un ejemplo. Procura que tu código sea lo más legible posible, de tal manera que te sea fácil revisarlo y mantenerlo, además de que será más fácil de analizar para quienes podemos echarte una mano.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

el problema viene por esta parte del código

```
  if($id_user_asignado == $iduserbucle){
                                echo '<td> <strong>'.$iniciocita.' a las '.$horainiciocita.'</strong> <br> '.$lisc['titulo'].'</td>';
                            }else{
                                echo '<td></td>';
                            }
```

Si el usuario no es el del bucle, entonces pinta el td vacío, quita el else de `echo '<td></td>';` Sería necesario agregar los tr para indicar que estas en una nueva fila

```
  if($cota = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_trabajadores)){
                    echo '<tr>'; //otro tr
                    do{

                        $iduserbucle = $cota['id'];
                        $fecha_inicio = $lisc['inicio'];
                        $iniciocita = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($fecha_inicio));
                        $horainiciocita = date("H:i", strtotime($fecha_inicio));
                        //Si no tiene trabajador asignado no mostramos nada 
                        if($iduserbucle != 0){
                            //Aqui tenemos un trabajador en cada vuelta. Comprobamos y si es de este mostramos datos, si no vacio 
                            if($id_user_asignado == $iduserbucle){
                                echo '<td> <strong>'.$iniciocita.' a las '.$horainiciocita.'</strong> <br> '.$lisc['titulo'].'</td>';
                            }
                        }       
                    }while($cota = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_trabajadores));
                    echo '</tr>'; //otro tr
                 }
```

Por último, también sería recomendable poner los tr al principio en las cabeceras ya que es la primera fila y es bueno que pongas la sintaxis de la tabla correcta

```
if($cota = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_trabajadores)){
                    echo '<tr>'; //poner el tr que necesitas
                    do{
                            echo' <th >'.$cota['nombre'].'</th>';
                    }while($cota = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_trabajadores));
                    echo '</tr>'; //poner el tr que necesitas
                 }
```

Comment: Gracias, pero claro si quito el echo '<td></td>' lo que hace es printarme todas las lineas en una columna

Comment: En tu ejemplo <tr>
       <td>Trabajador1</td>
       <td>Trabajador2</td>
       <td>Trabajador3</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td>03/01/2023 </td>
       <td>03/01/2023</td>
       <td>01/01/2023</td>
   </tr> Toda esa información ¿Corresponde al trabajador 1?

Comment: No, cada una es de un trabajador. EN mi ejemplo solo el trabajador 2 tiene 2 citas.

Comment: Te modifico mi comentario principal

Comment: Ok, lo he probado pero claro, en el momento en el que quito el else{ echo '<td></td>' }  me sale todos lso resultados en una unica fila, es decir, asi: <table><tr><td>trabajador1</td><td>trabajador2</td><td>trabajador3</td></tr><table><tr><td>01/01/2023</td><td></td><td></td></tr></tr><table><tr><td>03/01/2023</td><td></td><td></td></tr>

Comment: Cual es el volumen de datos? Debe ser exactamente un DataTable? Una vez me pidieron algo similar, con PHP puro y tablas dentro de una tabla se puede hacer. No digo que sea lo mas optimo pero de que se puede se puede.

Comment: Si como coment en el resultado,te sale un segundo <table> te falta código por pegar.